# Consumir api local desde flutter visual studio code

Tags: api, flutter

estoy teniendo problemas al usar api localhost(net core)

```
      final _prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String passowrd) async {
    final authData = {
      'Username': email,
      'Password': passowrd,
    };
    final resp = await http.post(
      '10.0.2.2:44394/api/User/authenticate',
      body: json.encode(authData),
    );
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(decodedResp);
    if (decodedResp.containsKey('token')) {
      _prefs.token = decodedResp['token'];

      return {'ok': true, 'token': decodedResp['token']};
    } else {
      return {'ok': false, 'mensaje': decodedResp['error']['message']};
    }
  }
```

lo que intente

1)poner mi ip en el http.post('mi ip'.........)

2)poner en el emulador de andriod studio mi ip y tampoco

el error que me arroja
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una URL empieza por el protocolo: "http://", "https://"...

Comment: ups, tienes razon aun no estoy muy familiarizado con el consumo de api, sigue sin funcionar me tira esto ahora "Exception has occurred.
HandshakeException (HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354)))"

Comment: Error de SSL. Busca en Google, estará respondido miles de veces.